# JavaScript: modify form when user submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user clicks submit on a form, I want to modify the contents of one field and then submit. I've now tried about 20 different ways to do this, but none of them work. I'm able to recognize the submit event, cancel it, and modify the fields, but I'm **unable to submit the form again in the same event**. My latest attempt was with JQuery:

```
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = document.getElementById("categorySafari");
        var selection = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("category").value = selection;
        this.submit(); // <-- this doesn't work and nothing I've tried here works
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: "Submit is not a function"

Comment: of course you can't submit, you cancel each submit! heh... infinite loop? use a flag of some sort to determine if the cleanup has run on not, and don't `preventDefault()` if it's clean.

Comment: I think that you enter an infinite recursion because you always cancel the default behavior. You should change some attribute of the submit event in order to not cancel the default after the first reentry

Comment: There was no infinite loop. I got infinite loop earlier by using `$("form").submit();` at the last line. This way it's just unable to call the submit function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `e.preventDefault()` and the `this.submit()` call. That is preventing the form submission.

Comment: And also remove `this.submit()`, since the form will be submitted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put onClick event to your submit button and call function to handle your fields then from this function call submit form event.
[Here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) is how you can trigger form with js

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works correctly for me (Ubuntu+Chromium): http://codepen.io/swergas/pen/qROWbY

```
Values Posted

categorySafari  volvo
category    Volvo
```